# Paramiko/Pexpect on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, paramiko, pexpect

Can one use Pexpect or Paramiko on Google App Engine?
I know Paramiko requires pycrypto but Google App Engine provides the pycrypto library.

Comment: Even if Paramiko works, you will have to enable billing so you can use outbound sockets. Much of Pexpect won't work because it expects to create sub processes.  Have you looked at appengines runtime characteristics to see it even matches what you want to achieve?

Comment: @TimHoffman app engine says c extensions are not allowed but I don't know which other restrictions app engine has. This is why am asking.

Comment: pexpect for instance can run sub processes, but thats not possible in appengine.  You should read the rest of the sandbox restrictions.

Comment: There are restrictions on sockets as well https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/